# Add slider navigation using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i made this slider only using unordered list - http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/ZYPBem

And now i am trying to apply the javascript, but I'm having trouble changing the slider through the navigation. I tried to change the z -index of the slide chosen for 5000 and the others to 1, but did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hero-slider-navbar_item').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).data('slider');

    var actual = $('.hero-slider_item.' + actual);
    var notActual = $('.hero-slider_item').not(actual);

    actual.css('z-index', '5000');
    notActual.css('z-index', '1');

  })

});
```

What i am doing wrong here?

---

UPDATE:

HTML:

```
<main>
    <section class="hero">
            <ul class="hero-slider">
                    <li class="hero-slider_item one active">
                        <div class="container">
                                <h2 class="hero-slider_title">Test</h2>
                                <h3 class="hero-slider_subtitle">test</h3>
                            <p class="hero-slider_legend">algo</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hero-slider_item two">
                        <div class="container">
                                <h2 class="hero-slider_title">Test</h2>
                                <h3 class="hero-slider_subtitle">test</h3>
                                <p class="hero-slider_legend">algo</p>
                        </div>  
                    </li>
                    <li class="hero-slider_item three">
                        <div class="container">
                                <h2 class="hero-slider_title">Test</h2>
                                <h3 class="hero-slider_subtitle">test</h3>
                                <p class="hero-slider_legend">algo</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            </ul>
            <nav class="hero-slider-navbar">
     <div class="container">
                      <ul class="hero-slider-navbar_nav" role="navigation">
                          <li class="hero-slider-navbar_item" data-slider="one" ></li>
                            <li class="hero-slider-navbar_item" data-slider="two" ></li>
                            <li class="hero-slider-navbar_item" data-slider="three" ></li>
                      </ul>
    </div>
            </nav>
    </section>
    <!-- End hero -->
</main>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.hero-slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.hero-slider_item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.hero-slider_item.one {
  background: red;
  z-index: 3;
}
.hero-slider_item.two {
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}
.hero-slider_item.three{
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hero-slider-navbar {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
}
.hero-slider-navbar_nav {
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-slider-navbar_item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: what's the value of actual in this line before assigning it to actual variable var actual = $('.hero-slider_item.' + actual);

Comment: `var actual = $('.hero-slider_item.' + actual);` => `actual` is `undefined` here!

Comment: could you show your html and css?

Comment: And your `$(this)` doesn't have `data-slider`!

Comment: Of course they have @LShetty - <li class="hero-slider-navbar_item" data-slider="three" ></li>

Comment: why not use `display` ?

Comment: i think this way is easier @php_nub_qq, don't u?

Comment: where do you think `actual` will come from when you are getting value as `target`?

Comment: Definitely not, also you should use class names instead of styles. This way your code is cleaner and separated, not mixing css with js. Additionally it's way easier to pick "not actual" slides with class names.

Comment: so you think i should use display + active class?

Comment: So, a quick and dirty version here => [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPgaOL](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPgaOL) Is this what you were after?

Comment: Yes! LShetty, please answer the question if you want earn points. I made like this too -> http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/ZYPBem

Comment: var actual = $('.hero-slider_item.' + actual);  you must define actual to use it. It is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here you go. You were nearly there. I have only improved the code a bit whilst got it to work.

Demo@[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPgaOL)

```
$(function() {
    $('.hero-slider-navbar_item').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = $(this).data('slider');
      //Item corresponding to the clicked element
      var actual = $(['.hero-slider_item', '.', target].join(''));
      //And it's siblings
      var others = actual.siblings();
      actual.css('z-index', '5000');
      others.css('z-index', '1');
    });
});
```

Another way that doesn't require data-slider:

Demo@[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYxVZy)

```
$(function() {
    $('.hero-slider-navbar_item').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.hero-slider_item').eq($(this).index()).siblings().css({
        'z-index': 1
      }).end().css({
        'z-index': 10
      });
    });
});
```